# Change Wordpress page content weekly

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, wordpress-shortcode

I have a Wordpress page with a Weekly Menu for the restaurant, built using [Quick Restaurant Menu](https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/quick-restaurant-menu/) plugin.

The menu changes every week till up to 6  weeks, then returns for the first one and starts again.

Shortcode used is: `[erm_menu_fullweek id=11910]`

Now, only the ID needs to be changed inside the shortcode to display the next weeks menu.

Is there a php approach to change the page content in SQL with a cron, or WordPress plugin to schedule it to run by itself?

Comment: I'm not really sure about the requirements. Do you have menus for each of these 6 weeks? If so write a function to calculate the current week then call the appropriate menu.

Comment: Yes, there is an id to each menu "[erm_menu_fullweek id=11910]" But i don't know how to call them at a certain point of the week to be changed inside the page

Comment: How do you know the week number? I mean what is the logic/condition for that?
You don't have to change the code or anything I guess just apply the correct logic to find the week number.

Comment: No need to know the week number. Just start with week1 at feb1 for example, and change it after 7 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While using WordPress cron to change the post content is a possibility, creating a custom shortcode to generate periodically modified end shortcode is more powerful.

**This gives you the ability to change the shortcode tag, arguments (IDs), start date, interval duration directly from WordPress page/post edit screen without touching any code.**

Use custom shortcode `[mm1707_shortcode_rotator]` to generate your final shortcode. This can be useful if the end shortcode is changed in future or IDs that you want to rotate are changed. You can also enclose content between this shortcode if your end shortcode requires it.

Example 1: `[mm1707_shortcode_rotator shortcode="erm_menu_fullweek" args="1,2,3,4,5,6,7" start_date="2018-01-08" interval="1 week"]`

Example 2: `[mm1707_shortcode_rotator shortcode="erm_menu_fullweek" args="1,2,3,4,5,6,7" start_date="2018-01-08" interval="1 week"] some content here [/mm1707_shortcode_rotator]` in case your end shortcode required some content as well.

```
<?php
/**
 * Custom shortcode which generates another supplied shortcode with ID argument swapped per
 * specified time interval.
 *
 * @param  array  $atts {
 *     Array of attributes specifiying shortcode, arguments to rotate and time interval.
 *
 *     @type string $shortcode  Shortcode to execute.
 *     @type string $args       Comma seperated arguments to rotate per interval period.
 *     @type string $start_date Date from which rotation should be counted.
 *     @type string $intereval  Interval for rotation. Expects relative dates.
 *                              See http://php.net/manual/de/datetime.formats.relative.php.
 * }
 * @param  string $content Optional. Content passed to shortcode.
 * @return string|bool          Returns output of supplied shortcode with ID argument
 * as per calculated period or false when $shortcode and $args are not supplied
 */
function mm1707_shortcode_rotator( $atts = [], $content = null ) {
    if ( empty( $atts['shortcode'] ) || empty( $atts['args'] ) ) {
        return false;
    }

    // Normalize attribute keys, lowercase.
    $atts = array_change_key_case( (array) $atts, CASE_LOWER );

    // Convert IDs from string to array.
    $args = explode( ',', $atts['args'] );
    $args = array_map( 'trim', array_filter( $args ) );

    // Override default attributes with user attributes.
    $attributes = shortcode_atts(
        [
            'shortcode'  => '',
            'args'       => array(),
            'start_date' => '',
            'interval'   => '1week', // Expects relative dates. See http://php.net/manual/de/datetime.formats.relative.php.
        ], $atts
    );

    // Get the start date, if empty then first date of current year would be used.
    $start_date = empty( $attributes['start_date'] ) ? new DateTime( '1 Jan' ) : new DateTime( $attributes['start_date'] );

    // Get the rotation interval.
    $rotation_interval = $attributes['interval'];
    $rotation_interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString( $rotation_interval );

    // Create DatePeriod and iterate over it to count ocurrences.
    $rotation_period = new DatePeriod( $start_date, $rotation_interval, new DateTime() );
    $args_count      = count( $args );
    $rotation        = 0;

    foreach ( $rotation_period as $date ) {
        $rotation++;
        if ( $rotation > $args_count - 1 ) {
            $rotation = 0;
        }
    }

    // Build shortcode.
    $shortcode = sprintf( '[%1$s id="%2$s"]', $attributes['shortcode'], $args[ $rotation ] );
    if ( ! empty( $content ) ) {
        $content    = apply_filters( 'the_content', $content );
        $shortcode .= $content . '[/' . $attributes['shortcode'] . ']';
    }

    // Start output & return it.
    return do_shortcode( $shortcode );
}
add_shortcode( 'mm1707_shortcode_rotator', 'mm1707_shortcode_rotator' );
```

**This code would go inside your theme's `functions.php` file**

**Note: This code was tested and works perfectly.**

---

#### To take it further

You can safely upgrade this code to have an array of arguments passed as string instead of only IDs.

For example you can improvise the logic to accept multi dimensional array as `args="foo:'bar',id:'2039',color:'#CC000000'|foo:'bar2',id:'1890',color:'#FFF'"`.

- Parse first by `|` to get rotating arguments using `explode('|', $args);`.
- Then simply do `str_replace( array(':',','), array('=', ' '), $args[$rotation] );`
- Change **`id="%2$s"` to `%2$s`** in `$shortcode = "'" . sprintf( '[%1$s` **`id="%2$s"`**`]', $attributes['shortcode'], $args[ $rotation ] );`.

This will give you arguments string for end shortcode as `[shortcode foo='bar' id='2039' color='#cc000000']` when `$rotation = 0`;

Comment: Thank you for your help. Although i get the hint of the code and what is should be, but most of the the used php is new to me. It's working in a way, that the shortcode disappears in on the page, but the content does not apper in his place.

Comment: @SzékelyTamás There was a minor bug in the code which I corrected. I also tested it thoroughly in my local dev and it is working. For your purpose you should be adding `[mm1707_shortcode_rotator shortcode="erm_menu_fullweek" args="1,2,3,4,5,6,7" start_date="2018-01-08" interval="1 week"]` to your post/page. Both `shortcode` and `args` are mandatory fields. Otherwise it will return `false`, which is `empty` for shortcodes.

Comment: I really appreciate your help. Saved me a lot of time. :) However i had to put echo before do_shortcode (echo do_shortcode( $shortcode );)  to see result on the page.

Comment: @SzékelyTamás You are right. There is an unnecessary output buffering in the code. I updated the code by removing that and extra quotations `''` around the `$shortcode`. Now it returns `do_shortcode` output directly. As per my tests this should work perfectly.

Comment: Yes, i noticed the extra ' ' and removed it myself too. Works like charm. Tested it with 1 minute, and works. Thanks again. :)